# Can't share few FFMPEG encoded videos on WhatsApp

Tags: video, ffmpeg, whatsapp, processbuilder

I am using FFMPEG to stitch a video to another video. However, I have observed that few of these videos are not being shared on WhatsApp with the message "**Can't send this video. Choose a different video and try again**".

I am using the following command for stitching:

```
ffmpeg -y -i <input1> -i
 <input2> -filter_complex "color=black:input1Width x input1Height:d=(input1time + input2time -1)[base]
;[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v] scale = iw * min(input1Width / iw\\, input1Height / ih):ih * min(input1Width/iw\\,input1Height/ih),
pad=input1Width:input1Height:(input1Width-iw*min(input1Width/iw\\,input1Height/ih))/2:(input1Height -
 ih*min(input1Width/iw\\,input1Height/ih))/2,setsar=1:1,format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1.0:alpha=1,
setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+((input1Time - 1)/TB)[v1];[base][v0]overlay[tmp]; [tmp][v1]overlay,format=yuv420p[fv];
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=1[fa]" -map [fv] -map [fa] -crf 23 -c:v libx264 -b:v 300K 
-preset slow outputvideo.mp4
```

Here: input1Width - Input 1 Video's width, input1Height - Input 2 Video's height.

Interestingly running this command directly on terminal produces a file which plays correctly on media players and I am able to share it across platforms including WhatsApp.

However, the same command when triggered from a java code produces a similar file in terms of size, bit rate (near about same as produced when directly executed). I am running the same command from java using ProcessBuilder like:

```
ProcessBulider stitchVideoCommandArray = new ProcessBuilder(
                        "ffmpeg", "-y",
                        "-i", <input1>,
                        "-i", <input2>,
                        "-filter_complex", "color=black:" + String.valueOf(width) + "x" + String.valueOf(height) + ":d=" +
                        String.valueOf(originalVideoTime + ASSET_VIDEOSTREAM_DURATION - CROSS_FADE_TIME_DURATION) + "[base];" +
                        "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]scale=iw*" + String.valueOf(minMultiplicable) + ":ih*" + String.valueOf(minMultiplicable) +
                        ",pad=" + String.valueOf(width) + ":" + String.valueOf(height) + ":(" + String.valueOf(width) + "-iw*" + String.valueOf(minMultiplicable) + "/2" +
                        "):(" + String.valueOf(height) + "-ih*" + String.valueOf(minMultiplicable) + "/2)" + ",fade=in" +
                        ":st=0:d=" + String.valueOf(CROSS_FADE_TIME_DURATION) + ":alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+((" + String.valueOf(originalVideoTime - CROSS_FADE_TIME_DURATION) +
                        ")/TB)[v1];[base][v0]overlay[tmp];[tmp][v1]overlay,format=yuv420p[fv];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=1[fa]",
                        "-map", "[fv]",
                        "-map", "[fa]",
                        "-c:v", MP4Transcode.MP4VideoStreamEncoder.H264.videoEncoders,
                        "-b:v", "300K",
                        "-c:a", MP4Transcode.MP4AudioStreamEncoders.AAC.audioEncoders,
                        "-b:a", "128K",
                        "-crf", String.valueOf(constantRateFactor),
                        "-preset", presetRequired,
                    outputVideoPath
            );
```

I then use this object to execute the command using

> command.start()

and waiting for exitvalue using

> command.waitFor()

This also produces a file which I am able to play correctly on media players but was not successful in sharing the video on WhatsApp.

Also, the file produced by executing FFmpeg commands as mentioned above from java produces media files with their loudness slightly increased.

I am not able to figue out if it's video specific issue or something else. It only happens to few random videos.

Here are the links to videos with the problem:
input 1 - [input1Link](https://img0.ropose.com/video/1jb2aja/XECG_1509267934753_80a45c3b_a449.org.mp4)
input 2 - [inpt2Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_VG2ffI6P3uYjdMWVdscTlaTTA/view?usp=sharing)

**EDIT 1:**
To add, adding `-loglevel debug` in java command takes forever and I haven't seen it yet responding for even 5-6 minutes. However, using it directly from terminal returns quickly after processing.

Comment: probably not ur issue, but u may want to make sure u do not have issues related to 'moov atom ' not being located at the start of your output.  on diff tack,  ffprobe or just querying the bad files w 'ffmpeg -i badfile'  should show something being amiss .  does whatsapp publish list of allowable formats / encodings ?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't come across any published list of allowed formats/encodings. However, there are few links where people have tried various formats as in: https://www.quora.com/Which-video-formats-does-WhatsApp-support.

Comment: I tried moving `moov atom`  to beginning of output using qtfaststart python script. But still, this video is not being shared.

Comment: what about youtube uploads. any diff there regarding outcome using one of your 'good' vs 'bad' files?

Comment: I am able to share my both 'good' and 'bad' files on youtube, facebook, and Instagram. However, my 'bad' videos only fail when shared on WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if the audio stream of video is normalized using EBU R.128 filters, WhatsApp cannot process such a video. Only in this case, sending fails. In my case, one of the input videos had EBU R.128 normalization.